# Apimatic Python SDK returns ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python

I am following the [instructions here](https://apimatic.io/apidocs/cgaas-api/v/1_0#/python/getting-started/how-to-use) to use the Python SDK for Apimatic's API.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
apimatic
|
-- apimatic
|
-- test
|   | 
|   -- testsdk.py
|
-- requirements.txt
```

`testsdk.py` contains the following code:

```
from apimatic.apimatic_client import ApimaticClient
```

When I run `python3 test/testsdk.py` I get this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apimatic'

I get the same error when I run

`PYTHONPATH=../ python3 test/testsdk.py`

I have run `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those instructions are for working with PyCharm, which looks for the module a little differently than when you try to run this file directly from the command line.
PyCharm looks for the folder at the root of the project, but when you run it through the command line the import statement needs to be relative to the current directory.

You have two options here

- Move your 'testsdk.py' file to the outer 'apimatic' folder

or

- Move your inner 'apimatic' folder to the 'test' folder

Run your testsdk.py file now and it should work.